# GraphQL tridion docs query throws null pointer exception

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, graphql, dxd-11.1, pca

Hi I have been trying below graphql query to fetch tridion docs content but it throws null pointer exception, could someone please suggest me what is wrong here

```
query items($first: Int, $after: String, $inputItemFilter: InputItemFilter!, $inputSortParam: InputSortParam, $contextData: [InputClaimValue!]) {
    items(first: $first, after: $after, filter: $inputItemFilter, sort: $inputSortParam, contextData: $contextData) {
        edges {
            cursor
            node {
                ...ItemFields               

            }       
        }
    }
}fragment ItemFields on Item {
    id
    itemId
    itemType
    namespaceId
    owningPublicationId
    publicationId
    title
    lastPublishDate
    creationDate
    initialPublishDate
    updatedDate   
    ...CustomMetaFields
}
fragment CustomMetaFields on Item {
  customMetas {
    edges {
      node {
          id
          itemId
          key
          namespaceId
          publicationId
          value
          valueType    
      }
    }
  }
}
```

variables passed as

```
{
    "after": null,
    "inputItemFilter": {
        "and": [{
            "and": null,
            "customMeta": {
                "key": "ishversionref.object.id",
                "scope": null,
                "value": "35686",
                "valueType": null
            },
            "itemTypes": null,
            "keyword": null,
            "namespaceIds": [2],
            "or": null,
            "publicationIds": null,
            "schema": null
        }],
        "customMeta": {
            "key": "publicationtitle.generated.value",
            "scope": null,
            "value": "content_test",
            "valueType": null
        },
        "itemTypes": null,
        "keyword": null,
        "namespaceIds": [2],
        "or": null,
        "publicationIds": null,
        "schema": null
    },
    "inputSortParam": {
        "order": "Ascending",
        "sortBy": "ITEM_ID"
    },
    "first": 0,
    "contextData": [{
        "type": "STRING",
        "uri": "dxa:modelservice:model:type",
        "value": "R2"
    }, {
        "type": "STRING",
        "uri": "dxa:modelservice:content:type",
        "value": "MODEL"
    }, {
        "type": "BOOLEAN",
        "uri": "dxa:modelservice:model:entity:relativelinks",
        "value": "true"
    }, {
        "type": "STRING",
        "uri": "taf:request:parameters",
        "value": "{\"CONTENT_LENGTH\":[\"-1\"],\"QUERY_STRING\":[null],\"CONTENT_TYPE\":[null],\"PATH_INFO\":[\"/\"]}"
    }, {
        "type": "BOOLEAN",
        "uri": "taf:tcdl:render:link:relative",
        "value": "true"
    }]
}
```

error which is coming on response

```
2020-04-20 06:46:40,039 ERROR CustomDataFetcherExceptionHandler - Exception while fetching data (/items) : java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sdl.delivery.content.dataloaders.broker.builder.BrokerQueryBuilder.getCustomMetaValueByType(BrokerQueryBuilder.java:349)
    at com.sdl.delivery.content.dataloaders.broker.builder.BrokerQueryBuilder.buildCustomMetaCriteria(BrokerQueryBuilder.java:244)
    at com.sdl.delivery.content.dataloaders.broker.builder.BrokerQueryBuilder.buildCriteria(BrokerQueryBuilder.java:210)
    at com.sdl.delivery.content.dataloaders.broker.builder.BrokerQueryBuilder.buildQuery(BrokerQueryBuilder.java:186)
    at com.sdl.delivery.content.dataloaders.broker.builder.BrokerQueryBuilder.buildQueryWithConditions(BrokerQueryBuilder.java:160)
    at com.sdl.delivery.content.dataloaders.broker.builder.BrokerQueryBuilder.buildQueryWithSort(BrokerQueryBuilder.java:155)
    at com.sdl.delivery.content.dataloaders.broker.BrokerItemsCriteriaDataLoader.getItemsByAndSort(BrokerItemsCriteriaDataLoader.java:106)
    at com.sdl.delivery.content.model.core.datafetcher.ItemsConnectionDataFetcher.fetch(ItemsConnectionDataFetcher.java:39)
    at com.sdl.delivery.content.model.core.datafetcher.AbstractListDataFetcher.get(AbstractListDataFetcher.java:39)
    at graphql.annotations.connection.PaginatedDataConnectionFetcher.get(PaginatedDataConnectionFetcher.java:45)
    at graphql.annotations.connection.PaginatedDataConnectionFetcher.get(PaginatedDataConnectionFetcher.java:35)
    at graphql.annotations.dataFetchers.connection.ConnectionDataFetcher.get(ConnectionDataFetcher.java:49)
    at graphql.annotations.dataFetchers.connection.AsyncConnectionDataFetcher.lambda$get$0(AsyncConnectionDataFetcher.java:34)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
2020-04-20 06:46:40,041 ERROR ContentAPIGraphQLExecutor - Errors: [ExceptionWhileDataFetching{path=[items]exception=java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionlocations=[SourceLocation{line=2, column=2}]}]
```

Comment: Are the keys in your customMeta properties correct?

Comment: Hi @Neil, yes those properties are present with publication metadatas in tridion docs

Comment: The `customMeta/valueType = null` looks suspicious. Should that not have a value?

Comment: Hi @RickPannekoek, that's a good catch, thank you for that :), i tried graphql by removing customMeta/valueType it worked, also i tried by setting up customMeta/valueType="STRING" that also worked. so on dxa code i was missing  "customMetaCriteria.setValueType(CustomMetaValueType.STRING);", which is now working, Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Good to hear that that was indeed the problem and you found the way to fix it. I created an Answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that `customMeta/valueType = null`